# Control hardware (a Raman spectrometer) using Python

Tags: python, controls, external, hardware, executable

I have an old Raman spectrometer (one of these - http://www.camo.com/downloads/partners/deltanu/Inspector_Raman_Datasheet.pdf) and I'd like to write code, ideally in Python, that can provide it with input parameters, operate it and receive data from it.

The spectrometer connects to a PC via a USB, although it is assigned to a virtual COM port. I currently control it using an .exe file provided by the company that used to sell it, that I believe was produced using LabVIEW.

Is it possible to write my own code to control this sort of hardware? How can I pass parameters and commands to hardware? What information would I need to know to do this?

Although I'm a fairly proficient Python coder, this is a brand new area for me, so any advice on where to start would be super appreciated. I'm open to coding in another language if that would be more appropriate. And let me know if I need to provide any more info.

Cheers, Liam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A google search for the device model name and "programming manual" is usually where I start with something like this. Those keywords hopefully turn up something from the manufacturer that tells you how to do exactly what you're trying to do, and a lot of them include code samples. Unfortunately, with the little information I have on your device, I couldn't find anything. That's going to make it much, much harder.

Everything beyond this point is a guess based on what I've seen before. Typically, if a LabVIEW program interacts with a device over a virtual COM port, the program sends an ASCII command to the device using the protocol defined in the manual, and then receives ASCII data in return. You can try sniffing that data with the NI I/O Trace tool (http://www.ni.com/download/ni-io-trace-14.0.1/4914/en/) while running the manufacturer's application, and then trying to make sense of the flood of data that you see on that port.

It could also be a Modbus device, which may help you figure out the structure of the communication.

In short, this'll be tough without a programming manual, but there is some hope. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for this! Since you said some manufacturers give out the info I needed, I got in touch with them.

They gave me the baudrate, data length,  parity, stop bit and flow control of the serial connection to the instrument. They also gave me a list of ASCII commands that the instrument can understand.

I can now control the instrument using the Serial module in Python, which I've never used before but looks interesting. Thanks for your help!